# Detecting server locale encoding with PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, localization, locale

I'm using `setlocale` and `strftime` to display localized month names in Brazilian Portuguese:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
$meses = array();
for($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $meses[$m] = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
}
```

This works fine in my dev environment, but on the production server it fails for March (which in Portuguese is "março"). If I `utf8_encode` the month names, it works on the server, but on my dev environment I get a double-encoded output. I suspect that's because of different locale encodings on each machine. I guess the proper solution would be to install a UTF8 locale setting for pt_BR on the server, but I'd like to avoid that if possible (long story short, the server admins are, er, difficult).

Is it possible to detect the encoding of the current locale from PHP, so I can code around this issue, and make my code work regardless of the locale/encoding settings?

Comment: What if you use `pt_BR.utf8` as locale?

Comment: Can you add the output from `locale -a` on server and dev?

Comment: You need to change production server's charset, maybe it's not set as UTF-8 as your dev server.

Comment: @hek2mgl pt_BR.utf8 apparently works on the remote server (from php-cli), but on dev it returns the months in English.

Comment: @hek2mgl locale -a gives 3 values on the remote (linux) server: pt_BR, pt_BR.iso88591 and pt_BR.utf8. On (osx) dev I got pt_BR, pt_BR.ISO8859-1, pt_BR.UTF-8 (isn't that standardized?!)

Comment: Note the difference: `pt_BR.UTF-8` <-> `pt_BR.utf8` Make sure that the locale has the same name on both server and dev. Or better: Add the localename as an config value

Comment: @hek2mgl I see that; what if I `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')`, and if it returns false I do it again with `.utf8`?

Comment: Should work. I would prefer something like `setlocale(get_app_config('localename'));`

Comment: @hek2mgl You're right, I believe that's the answer, define the locale in a config file and use that. If you post it as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments below the question we could resolve the problem. It was caused because the locale names differed on both systems one used `pt_BR.uft-8` the other `pt_BR.UTF8`.

Finally we agreed to define the locale in a config file and use that.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
echo setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0); // en_US.UTF-8
```

to get the current encoding and then work around it.

Passing zero to `setLocale` gives you locale values. In this case we are getting the value for `LC_CTYPE` setting.

Comment: That gives me "C" before calling setlocale, and "pt_BR" afterwards. How could I use that output to detect the encoding? By trying to set e.g. `.UTF-8`, then using it to check if it worked?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out with hek2mgl that using a config file to store the locale name would be cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

To get the encoding used by strftime use

```
 mb_internal_encoding()
```

to convert the stftime encoded string to utf-8, use

```
mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', mb_internal_encoding());
```

Comment: strftime has nothing to do with the multibyte string library. it uses the currently set locale (see getlocale/setlocale).

Comment: @Dakusan strftime returns character set encoded characters, so it uses both locale and a character set, you are talking about the locale while I'm talking about the character set, there is nothing wrong with the answer :)

Comment: "To get the encoding used by strftime use mb_internal_encoding()" This is patently wrong. mb_internal_encoding() can be utf-8 while strftime WILL return either windows1252 or utf16 on windows. I believe those are the only 2 encodings in windows has, so your code would obviously not work in all scenarios. It would only work when the locale's charset is set to the same thing as mb_internal_encoding(). The return from strftime doesn't give a crap what the mb_internal_encoding is.

Comment: @Dakusan that is news to me, what can you use to find out the character encoding for strftime?

Comment: That's the point of this thread :) - I have not found an easy way to do it, but depending on your system (Linux supports most charsets, I think?), you can just make sure you define your locale charset properly as utf8. e.x. 'en_us.UTF-8'. So make it more of a configuration thing than a trying-to-find-out thing. mb_detect_encoding is designed to do this, but I have my doubts as to its fullproofness. I'm very surprised there isnt a library out there that just allows you to throw a few special characters at it to give you a definite encoding.